# Why does MySQL COUNT function sometimes do a full table scan and other times use an index? And how can this be avoided?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, count

In a current web project of mine, we are implementing a complex search function. As part of that search functionality, we are using the MySQL `COUNT` function to be able to return the number of matching results.

We are running into a performance hiccup as a result. When getting the actual list of results, MySQL properly uses the indexes we have setup and returns results very quickly. When using the `COUNT` query, however, the results are sometimes returned very slowly. When examining the execution plans for various search queries, we have discovered that sometimes the `COUNT` query is doing a full table scan. Other times, despite the query logic being practically identical, the query is using an index. We can't seem to notice any particular pattern that distinguishes the two.

Here is an example of a query that is NOT doing a full table scan:

```
select  COUNT(DISTINCT text.name) AS count
    from  `text_epigraphy`
    inner join  `text`  ON `text`.`uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
    inner join  `hierarchy`  ON `hierarchy`.`uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
    inner join  `text_epigraphy` as `t1`  ON `t1`.`text_uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
      and  `t1`.`reading_uuid` in ('01f1e805-1278-ec9b-9f69-fced97bc923e',
                '07a120bc-02ec-c1ac-e0ba-532de39766ed', '126f978b-bd99-40f0-8f3b-d2bcec1ed3fe',
                '44ec304e-71f4-4995-a30d-0ca6d3bec95a', '4a1d8673-9e30-2d1e-7b87-453dec2886db',
                'bce40e36-d6eb-c44a-d114-8c7653a0e68c', 'c9083b77-6122-7933-ea21-63d3777749f3' )
      and  t1.char_on_tablet=text_epigraphy.char_on_tablet + 1
      and  t1.line=text_epigraphy.line
    inner join  `text_epigraphy` as `t2`  ON `t2`.`text_uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
      and  `t2`.`reading_uuid` in ('3fc156dc-e831-493e-5dc1-84a547aeb4fa',
                '70f9be19-62b6-3fe8-ddda-32bd50a8d36e' )
      and  t2.char_on_tablet=text_epigraphy.char_on_tablet + 2
      and  t2.line=text_epigraphy.line
    inner join  `text_epigraphy` as `t3`  ON `t3`.`text_uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
      and  `t3`.`reading_uuid` in ('1ee91402-ebb0-3be9-cc38-9d4187816031',
                '25a44259-fe7a-2b73-6e2c-02171c924805', 'a23fd531-c796-353e-4a53-54680248438a',
                'd55fa6ad-c523-2e33-6378-b4f2e2a020f1' )
      and  t3.char_on_tablet=text_epigraphy.char_on_tablet + 3
      and  t3.line=text_epigraphy.line
    where  `text_epigraphy`.`reading_uuid` in ('6c0e47d0-00aa-26fb-e184-07038ca64323',
                'd8904652-f049-11f9-3f7a-038f1e3b6055', 'eca27c41-d3ca-417c-15e0-db5353ddaefb' )
      and  1 = 1
      and  (1 = 1
              or  1 = 0)
    limit  1
```

[image: Execution plan for query without full table scan]

And yet this query IS doing a full table scan:

```
select  COUNT(DISTINCT text.name) AS count
    from  `text_epigraphy`
    inner join  `text`  ON `text`.`uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
    inner join  `hierarchy`  ON `hierarchy`.`uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
    inner join  `text_epigraphy` as `t1`  ON `t1`.`text_uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
      and  `t1`.`reading_uuid` in ('3fc156dc-e831-493e-5dc1-84a547aeb4fa')
      and  t1.char_on_tablet=text_epigraphy.char_on_tablet + 1
      and  t1.line=text_epigraphy.line
    inner join  `text_epigraphy` as `t2`  ON `t2`.`text_uuid` = `text_epigraphy`.`text_uuid`
      and  `t2`.`reading_uuid` in ('1ee91402-ebb0-3be9-cc38-9d4187816031',
                '25a44259-fe7a-2b73-6e2c-02171c924805', 'a23fd531-c796-353e-4a53-54680248438a',
                'd55fa6ad-c523-2e33-6378-b4f2e2a020f1' )
      and  t2.char_on_tablet=text_epigraphy.char_on_tablet + 2
      and  t2.line=text_epigraphy.line
    where  `text_epigraphy`.`reading_uuid` in ('c9083b77-6122-7933-ea21-63d3777749f3')
      and  1 = 1
      and  (1 = 1
              or  1 = 0)
    limit  1
```

[image: Execution plan for query with full table scan]

Like I said, we can't quite figure out why some searches are doing a full table scan when using `COUNT` but it is resulting in significantly slower searches. If anyone could help us figure out what is causing the difference and how we might be able to avoid the full table scan or at least optimize the queries.

Comment: Could you post the table schema?

Comment: We _must_ see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we know what the index is that it is using in one case an eschewing in the other case.

Comment: two queries with different predicate sets (one with significantly bounded literals) using different plans ? Who would have imagined that </sarcasm>. These queries are a very long way from "practically identical".

Answer (score 0):

Can't you remove `hierarchy`?

What indexes exist on `text_epigraphy`?  This looks useful:

```
INDEX(line, char_on_tablet, reading_uuid, text_uuid)
```

On `text`:  `INDEX(uuid, name)`

After that, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT`; then I will look at your question.